# How to recover an Algorand Wallet with Python AlgoSDK?

Tags: python, blockchain, wallet

Although the official algosdk (Python SDK for Algorand) documentation suggests that a wallet can be recovered by simply invoking the following function ([link](https://py-algorand-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1_a/kmd.html)):

```
create_wallet(name, pswd, driver_name='sqlite', master_deriv_key=None)
```

with the fourth argument:

```
master_deriv_key (str, optional) – if recovering a wallet, include
```

wallet recovery does not work in my code and leads to experience an exception as well. Also the official Algorand documentation shows how to use the abovementioned function for recovering a wallet ([link](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/features/accounts/create/#recover-wallet-and-regenerate-account)):

```
# recover the wallet by passing mdk when creating a wallet
new_wallet = kcl.create_wallet("MyTestWallet2", "testpassword", master_deriv_key=mdk)
```

Below, you can watch at my code, a very simple snippet that I coded to make some tests with Algorand SDK:

```
from algosdk import kmd
from algosdk import mnemonic

kmd_clt = kmd.KMDClient('855d39510cce40caf11de4c941b37632d1529ec970156214528a33a0ae8473b4', 'http://127.0.0.1:6969')
if kmd_clt:
    kmd_wlt_mdk = None
    kmd_wlt_list = kmd_clt.list_wallets()
    for kmd_wlt in kmd_wlt_list:
        kmd_name = kmd_wlt['name']
        kmd_id = kmd_wlt['id']
        if kmd_name == 'wallet_name':
            kmd_wlt_hdl = kmd_clt.init_wallet_handle(kmd_id, 'wallet_password')
            if kmd_wlt_hdl:
                kmd_wlt_mdk = kmd_clt.export_master_derivation_key(kmd_wlt_hdl, 'wallet_password')
            break
    if kmd_wlt_mdk:
        kmd_wlt = kmd_clt.create_wallet('wallet_name', 'wallet_password', master_deriv_key=kmd_wlt_mdk)
        kmd_wlt_hdl = kmd_clt.init_wallet_handle(kmd_wlt['id'], 'wallet_password')
        acc_addr_list = kmd_clt.list_keys(kmd_wlt_hdl)
        for acc_addr in acc_addr_list:
            account_address = acc_addr
            print(account_address)
            account_key = kmd_clt.export_key(kmd_wlt_hdl, 'wallet_password', account_address)
            print(account_key)
            account_mnemonic = mnemonic.from_private_key(account_key)
            print(account_mnemonic)
```

Below, you can watch at the Traceback and the error message returned at run-time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/algosdk/kmd.py", line 63, in kmd_request
    resp = urlopen(req)
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/algosdk/kmd.py", line 67, in kmd_request
    raise error.KMDHTTPError(json.loads(e)["message"])
algosdk.error.KMDHTTPError: wallet with same name already exists

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "algorand_test.py", line 49, in <module>
    kmd_wlt = kmd_clt.create_wallet('emiliano', 'emiliano', master_deriv_key=kmd_wlt_mdk)
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/algosdk/kmd.py", line 118, in create_wallet
    return self.kmd_request("POST", req, data=query)["wallet"]
  File "/home/emiliano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/algosdk/kmd.py", line 69, in kmd_request
    raise error.KMDHTTPError(e)
algosdk.error.KMDHTTPError: {
  "error": true,
  "message": "wallet with same name already exists"
}
```

It seems to be clear how the `create_wallet` function is the sinner of such behavior which leads to get back the error "wallet with same name already exists". Internals of Algorand SDK are very simple, APIs are wrappers for REST methods. Function `create_wallet` does simply ([link](https://github.com/algorand/py-algorand-sdk/blob/develop/algosdk/kmd.py#L96)):

```
def create_wallet(self, name, pswd, driver_name="sqlite",
                  master_deriv_key=None):
    """
    Create a new wallet.
    Args:
        name (str): wallet name
        pswd (str): wallet password
        driver_name (str, optional): name of the driver
        master_deriv_key (str, optional): if recovering a wallet, include
    Returns:
        dict: dictionary containing wallet information
    """
    req = "/wallet"
    query = {
        "wallet_driver_name": driver_name,
        "wallet_name": name,
        "wallet_password": pswd
    }
    if master_deriv_key:
        query["master_derivation_key"] = master_deriv_key
    return self.kmd_request("POST", req, data=query)["wallet"]
```

I'm sure the master derivation key passed in input is correct since I've alredy checked it with the `goal` command from console.

Has anyone else experienced this type of problem before?

Comment: Your error states `400: Bad Request` it means that your SDK is doing some wrong request to server. It usually means that SDK is outdated. Have you checked if this sdk was recently developed in last month?

Comment: Latest version. I think Bad Request is much more related to the fact that the argument "master_derivation_key" is completely ignored when parsing "query" at server side, thus leading to try to create a new wallet instead of recovering it as suggested by the documentation.

Comment: Have you also tried doing any non-working SDK command by hand through doing low level HTTP request? E.g. using `requests` library. It can be the case that online documentation about API is wrong. Then the only way to fix a problem is to contact API developers support.

Comment: Not yet done. Let's say, this work is not so critical right now, there's not an approaching deadline, so I preferred to query first the stack-overflow community to verify there's anyone else who ran into the same problem and to determine in primis if it is a bug in the SDK. Anyway, I'll surely do that try at a later time so that I will be able to reply to you with an answer and to contact API developers.

Comment: First you may try to read API description on their official website, I mean not SDK documentation, but REST API documentation on cryptocurrency website. Then try to send request directly to website API through HTTP request using library like `requests`. If your HTTP request doesn't fail and succeeds then probably bug is in SDK. Otherwise bug is inside cryptocurrency official API documentation (then you need to contact developers).

Comment: @Arty Yes, I know what you mean. I did that try as you suggested. This is the result:

curl -X POST -H "X-KMD-API-Token: 855d39510cce40caf11de4c941b37632d1529ec970156214528a33a0ae8473b4" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"wallet_driver_name": "sqlite", "wallet_name": "emiliano", "wallet_password": "emiliano", "master_derivation_key": "bURByLn4BT1JbdOvUL9hU+eeobdjkZMELRNNV/KtinE="}' http://127.0.0.1:6969/v1/wallet

{
  "error": true,
  "message": "wallet with same name already exists"
}

As you may see the REST API returns the same issue returned by urllib.

Comment: If you made all params exactly according to REST API doc then definitely there is a bug either in their documentation or API code implementation. Usually cryptocurrency developers have active support and reply frequently.

Comment: Actually REST API Doc doesn't suggest MDK is the optional parameter to retrive a wallet even if it is indicated as an optional one (https://developer.algorand.org/docs/reference/rest-apis/kmd/#post-v1wallet). Rather, the SDK Doc suggests that MDK is used specifically to recover an existing wallet. I agree completely with your "either...or..." sentence and the active support should be notified of this.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, Algorand documentation of REST APIs doesn't suggest explicitly to use the Master-Derivation-Key to retrieve a Wallet when making a `POST /v1/wallet` ([link](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/reference/rest-apis/kmd/#post-v1wallet)). Conversely, Algorand documentation of Python SDK suggests that the Master-Derivation-Key can be passed to the `create_wallet` function, which then makes the HTTP POST stated before, to recover an existing Wallet ([link](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/features/accounts/create/#recover-wallet-and-regenerate-account)).

As explained within my question above, `create_wallet` fails to recover the Wallet because the underlying `POST /v1/wallet` fails. At the suggestion of @Arty, this has been proved as follow:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "X-KMD-API-Token: <kmd-token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"wallet_driver_name": "sqlite", "wallet_name": <wallet-name>, "wallet_password": <wallet-password>, "master_derivation_key": <master-derivation-key>}' <kmd-address-and-port>/v1/wallet
```

which returned

```sh
{ "error": true, "message": "wallet with same name already exists" }
```

I notified this problem to the Algorand support and I'm currently waiting for a reply. Anyhow, in order to give some sense to the question's title, I want to share another possible solution to recover a Wallet still by relying on the Python SDK:

```py
from algosdk import kmd
from algosdk import wallet
from algosdk import mnemonic

kmd_clt = kmd.KMDClient(<kmd-token>, <kmd-address-and-port>)
if kmd_clt:
    kmd_wlt_mdk = None
    kmd_wlt_list = kmd_clt.list_wallets()
    for kmd_wlt in kmd_wlt_list:
        kmd_name = kmd_wlt['name']
        kmd_id = kmd_wlt['id']
        if kmd_name == <wallet-name>:
            kmd_wlt_hdl = kmd_clt.init_wallet_handle(kmd_id, <wallet-password>)
            if kmd_wlt_hdl:
                kmd_wlt_mdk = kmd_clt.export_master_derivation_key(kmd_wlt_hdl, <wallet-password>)
            break
    if kmd_wlt_mdk:
        wlt = wallet.Wallet(<wallet-name>, <wallet-password>, kmd_clt, mdk=kmd_wlt_mdk)
        if wlt:
            acc_addr_list = wlt.list_keys()
            for acc_addr in acc_addr_list:
                account_address = acc_addr
                print(account_address)
                account_key = wlt.export_key(acc_addr)
                print(account_key)
                account_mnemonic = mnemonic.from_private_key(account_key)
                print(account_mnemonic)
```

I hope it will be useful to someone else in the future.